# Encoding with JS base64 and deciding with php base64_decode

Tags: javascript, php, base64, decode, encode

I'm sending users to a new link which has a value that is encoded with Javascript's btoa, however, on the PHP side, when I decode it and echo the value out, the value that is echoed out is "undefined"

```
    $("#btn-print-bonus").click(function(){
        var id = btoa(id);
        window.open('/pdf/?type=bonus&id='+id+'&name='+fullname+'');
    });
```

php file

```
$id = base64_decode($_GET["id"]);
echo $id;
```

Comment: Where does `fullname` and `id` come from? If you open the browser developer tools and set a breakpoint on the click handler, you might be able to see what the argument to window.open will be.

Comment: PHP will never generate the `undefined` keyword by itself because it has no special meaning in the language. I'm pretty sure you have a literal `undefined` encoded in Base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the problem - `var id = btoa(id);`

var id will "mask" any var named id outside of that click callback, so in effect you are doing

```
var id = undefined;
id = btoa(id);
```

Which results in id=dW5kZWZpbmVk passed to php - check in the developer tools network tab and see if I'm right

dW5kZWZpbmVk is the string "undefined" base64 encoded - btoa coerces the given argument to a string